# how correctly set xml to RichTextBox in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a xml code:

```
<Paragraph>Download it directly to the <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://itunes.apple.com/fi/app/goalapp/id502461189?ls=1&mt=8">iTunes Store</Hyperlink> or <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://market.android.com/details?id=com.strikersoft.meramal.se">Android Market</Hyperlink>. The application is launched for Swedish app store.</Paragraph>
```

richTextBox.Xaml = xml;

But in this case I have an error, so how correctly set xaml to RichTextBox in Windows Phone?

**Update**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic Usage or the RichTextBox based on the code posted:

```
<RichTextBox 
    Width="400" Height="400" 
    Background="Transparent" 
    BorderBrush="White" 
    BorderThickness="3">
    <Paragraph>Download it directly to the 
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://itunes.apple.com/fi/app/goalapp/id502461189?ls=1&amp;mt=8" TargetName="_blank">iTunes Store</Hyperlink> 
        or <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://market.android.com/details?id=com.strikersoft.meramal.se" TargetName="_blank">Android Market</Hyperlink>. 
        The application is launched for Swedish app store.
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

**Note**: when creating URL's, the URL must be encoded, i.e., when using ampersands (&) in a URL, they should be created as `&amp;` and the `NavigateUri` needs the `TargetName="_blank"` attribute added to open in the browser.

**Edit**

When setting the `XAML` property in code, the xml namespace needs to be included in the xml. Wrap the entire xml block (and be sure to encode the URL as noted above) in a `Section` node:

```
<Section 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Paragraph>
    Download it directly to the
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://itunes.apple.com/fi/app/goalapp/id502461189?ls=1&amp;mt=8" TargetName="_blank">iTunes Store</Hyperlink>
    or <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://market.android.com/details?id=com.strikersoft.meramal.se" TargetName="_blank">Android Market</Hyperlink>.
    The application is launched for Swedish app store.
  </Paragraph>
</Section>
```

In the code behind, make sure the XML is a string, i.e.,:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("MyDoc.xml");
richTextBox.Xaml = xml.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do what in code? Create the entire RichTextBox? Or create the Hyperlinks? Or create the paragraph? Or?

Comment: I have i RichText box: RichTextBox richTextBox=new RichTextBox (); I need to set this xml to it content in c# code not in view

Comment: In your question you state "I have a xaml code:" is that the XAML? or the XML? Can you post the entire XML?

Comment: there is just an empty place where the hyperlink should be

Comment: If you use just the XML that you provided, does that work? If so, then there is something else going on in the XML as it appears there is quite a bit more XML than was included in the question. From my tests, everything works fine as posted in my answer.

Comment: now I have found the problem - the coloutr of hyperlinks is white) thenks a lot for help)

Comment: I was just about to suggest that the hyperlinks may be white in your app :)  Also, note that the hyperlinks need the attribute of `TargetName="_blank"` added.

Comment: "when using ampersands (&) in a URL, they should be created as &amp;" - thank you very much!